# How to pass arguments to a PhantomJS script from Selenium/Ghostdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I what to execute a `phantomJS` script which download a webpage (args[1]) and save the result html into a file (args[2]) as follows:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

// Set the url address and the path
var url = system.args[1];
var path = system.args[2];

page.open(url, function () {
   fs.write(path, page.content, 'w');
   phantom.exit();
});
```

I am using `selenium/ghostdriver` to execute the script as follows:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,".../phantomjs");

String [] phantomJsArgs = {url,path};
cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_CLI_ARGS, phantomJsArgs);

PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(cap);          
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(scriptPath)),Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
driver.executePhantomJS(content);
```

This code works except when I try to pass from `selenium/ghostdriver` 2 parameters call `url` and `path`to the phantomJS script as `system.args[1]` and `system.args[2]`. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: This is a really strange way of executing a PhantomJS script. If you use the Java bindings for Selenium, then you really should be using its API. If you want to call a plain PhantomJS script from Java, then invoke the PhantomJS binary as a subprocess with the script. Please don't mix both, because you will almost certainly run into problems when this gets a little more complicated.

Comment: Do you mean call the PhantomJS script like a process instead of using Ghostdriver? I do not quite understand what you are saying about "you really should be using its API". Am I not doing it already?

Comment: Yes, I mean that you should use `Runtime#exec` or similar instead of executing the same script through Ghostdriver when you have a script. If you are not limited to a script, then you should use the API like opening a page with the `driver` and getting it's page source.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just pass arguments to executePhantomJS method?

```
driver.executePhantomJS(content, url, path);
```

Comment: Using what you say give the following args in the script: `main.js,--ip=,--port=36863,--logFile=phantomjsdriver.log,--logColor=false,--logLevel=INFO`. There is not a url arg or a path arg.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to resolve the problem was instead of passing the 2 parameters as arguments (we are not in a command line), what I did was to edit the file as a string and replace the values of those two variables with `String.replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

use arguments[0], arguments[1], ... to reference args.
http://javadox.com/com.github.detro.ghostdriver/phantomjsdriver/1.1.0/org/openqa/selenium/phantomjs/PhantomJSDriver.html